# Is it possible to recreate tensorflow prediction script for a saved model when you don't have the training code or original prediction/test code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to recreate predict file for an image classifier that is created in tensorflow. The model files I have is 4 files: checkpoint, model.ckpt.index, model.ckpt.meta and model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001

When I ran a piece of code that got all the tensor names. It returned that there 10 tensor names from Variable, Variable_1 to Variable_9 where they each had Variable_(number goes here)/Adam and Variable_(number goes here)/Adam_1 as well as beta1_power and beta2_power.

Is there any chance of creating the predict code for this? Thanks. I would be able to map the predictions if values were returned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [import_meta_graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph) on the `model.ckpt.meta` file to reconstruct the original graph structure of your model. You can then use [init_from_checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/init_from_checkpoint) on the directory containing the `checkpoint` file to re-initialize the trained model for prediction.